# Create a installable PWA (web app) of an existing Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, progressive-web-apps

I've created an app in Rails which can be put on the homescreen of an iPhone. With some javascript hacking, I can make sure all internal requests stay within that frame. While this works, there are also some drawbacks. With the rise of PWA, I was wondering whether that would be a good alternative, so my questions:

- Isn't PWA overkill if my only requirement is that the app is instalable?
- Do I need to install all the service workers to get the PWA installable?
- Is there some alternative I might have overlooked?

Comment: Dig deeper in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/). You will find something more interesting about PWA. Also, for your 2nd question, check the project flow [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. From [google's PWA site](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/):

> Progressive Web Apps are user experiences that have the reach of the web, and are:
>   **Reliable** - Load instantly and never show the downasaur, even in uncertain network conditions.
>   **Fast** - Respond quickly to user interactions with silky smooth animations and no janky scrolling.
>   **Engaging** - Feel like a natural app on the device, with an immersive user experience.
>   This new level of quality allows Progressive Web Apps to *earn a place on the **user's home screen**.*

So my answer for your first question is, no. It's not overkill, it's exactly for that (and more, but you don't have to implement all the available features).

2. If you want the user to feel like the user is on a native app, yes you have to. There are a lot of basic service workers and builder to use that enable basic caching already.
   [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist) is a checklist from google on what you need to have a "proper" PWA.
   Microsoft suggests [this site](https://www.pwabuilder.com/) to get you started for basic modern websites.
3. Except for using something like Cordova, I don't see any alternative for PWA's that suite your use case, the only alternative I see is leave it as it is, if you don't need a PWA. The hype is currently high and you should definitley check it out. But as always, you don't have to if your product works as it should.